# ssl certifcate not verified while installing numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pip

**problem during installing numpy using the command given below in command prompt.**
     tried to install metplotlib ,numpy , scipy but the facing same problem 
     everytime .below is the error in numpy installation

```
> cd ..
> cd ..
> cd pyhton36
> cd scripts 
> pip install numpy
 collecting numpy

 Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, 
status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: 
CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:841)'),)': 
/simple/numpy/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/numpy/: There was a problem 
confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', 
port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/numpy/ (Caused by 
SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify 
failed (_ssl.c:841)'),)) - skipping
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: 
)
No matching distribution found for numpy
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem 
confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', 
port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by 
SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify 
failed (_ssl.c:841)'),)) - skipping


so how can i correct this or can i install it in another way
I used command pip list :

package    version

pip        10.0.1

setuptools 39.0.1

Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem        confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:841)'),)) - skipping
```

deleted python3.6.6 and installed python3.4.4 and now the command pip         install numpy showing the error :

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for numpy

Comment: Do you have openssl installed?

Comment: Are you on a corporate network?  If so, contact your network or system administrator and ask them, because they might be intercepting your SSL traffic which can cause this problem.

Comment: no i have not installed openssl

Comment: no i am using private network

Comment: @NitinThakur, as far as I know `python` use `openssl` libraries for SSL/TLS operations. So you can try to install `openssl` and check again

Comment: how can i install open ssl

Comment: @NitinThakur, what is your Operating System?

Comment: windows, I am using window 10 now

Answer (score 0):

use this command instead of 'pip install numpy'. This ended up working for me.

> pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org numpy